# How to pass a setter hook to a child component and satisfy TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to pass a setter hook (setValuesList) from the parent (App.tsx) to the childcomponent (AddNumber.tsx)

I defined the hook in the parent component like this:

```
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

And I want to pass the hook to the childcomponent like this:

```
<AddNumber valuesList={valuesList} setValuesList={setValuesList} />
```

However I get a Typescript error:

```
(JSX attribute) AppProps.setValuesList: (num: number) => void
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>' is not assignable to type '(num: number) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'num' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number[]>'.ts(2322)
AddNumber.tsx(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setValuesList' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AppProps'
```

In the childcomponent I am defining an interface for the props like this:

```
interface AppProps {
  valuesList: number[];
  setValuesList: (num: number) => void;
}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

my repository is at: https://github.com/acandael/number-list

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This the type definition for `useState` hook

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

So if you pass the type `number[]` for the state value when calling `useState` the type for the setter function will be `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>`

```
import { SetStateAction } from 'react';

// this interface will satisfy if you want to pass setValuesList directly
interface AppProps {
  valuesList: number[];
  setValuesList: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>;
 
  // setValuesList: (val: number[]) => void  will also satisfy, but it is
  // better to be explict and pass React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>
}
```

if you don't want to modify the interface you can create and pass another function.

```js
// you don't need to modify the interface if you take this approach -
// the interface already satisfies the type required in this case
const updateValue = (num: number) => {
 setValuesList(prev => prev.concat(num))
}

<AddNumber valuesList={valuesList} setValuesList={updateValue} />
```

Comment: thanks for your help @subashMahapatra
I set the interface to: setValuesList: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>;
But I get this error: Cannot find name 'SetStateAction'

Comment: `import { SetStateAction } from react` or use `React.SetStateAction`

Comment: you can do the same thing with `Dispatch` either import from 'react' or use `React.Dispatch`

Comment: I imported { SetStateAction }. This seem to work. However when I try to call the hook like this:
props.setValuesList(number);
I get the error:
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number[]>'.

Comment: because the state value is of type `number[]` i.e an array of numbers, If you need to call the `setValues` function with a number try the second part of the answer **You don't need to modify the interface for the second approach part of the answer**

Comment: thanks @subashMahapatra, that worked. I'll mark your response as the solution

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're assigning the wrong thing to the wrong type.
`setValuesList` is callable but is of type `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>` which is obviously different from `(num: number) => void`.

I see two ways of resolving this:

- change the type of `setValueList` in `AppProps` to `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>` (there's also the cheaty `any` type, but I don't recommend it if you can avoid it).
- You wrap setValuesList in a function (should look like `(num: number) => setValuesList(num)`), that does what you want and will respect the type system

For the second solution, good canditates could also be `useCallback` or `useMemo`, but I'm not familiar enough with them... But looking at the docs might help you out.

Comment: thanks @ShadowMitia for your help. I'll try to change the type of setValueList in AppProps, but what type should I change it to?

Comment: You can try to change it to `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>`.

Comment: I changed it to 'setValuesList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>'
but I get this error: Cannot find name 'Dispatch'
I guess I should import 'Dispatch'?

Comment: Yes, but you can also use React.Dispatch, like in subashMahapatra's answer

Answer (score 0):

The setter function from `useState` is of type `Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>`

If you want your interface to work you should pass `(num: number) => void` function type:

```
<AddNumber
  valuesList={valuesList}
  setValuesList={(num: number) => {
    setValuesList(num);
  }}
/>
```